# basename execution on remote node

Tags: bash, ssh, basename

```
ssh  ubuntu@$ip -n "aws s3 cp s3://bucket/$userlistlocation . --region eu-central-1 ; fbname=$(basename '$userlistlocation') ; echo "$fbname""
```

This above command is part of  jenkins job. 
userlistlocation --> where user input will be in this below format foldername/filename.csv

I want to print only filename here for this purpose i am using basename. Executing manually working fine. But if i try to run this on remote machine it's executing upto file download. It's not executing basename part

File which i download will be source file for command execution.

Comment: You have a quoting problem. Easiest way: Write a script on the remote, with correct quoting. Then run it via ssh.

Comment: We have  aws OD boxes for every release we will terminate the existing machines. This will be problem.

Comment: Previous comment ignored, as I know now what it is saying.

Comment: Where is `userlistlocation` being set? Sounds like the variable is missing on the remote machine.

Comment: @Panki userlistlocation user input from jenkins job. For testing purpose assigned the value explicitly on server from where this job has to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out finally thank you @Kusalananda

```
 ssh  ubuntu@$ip -n "aws s3 cp s3://bucket/$userlistlocation . --region eu-central-1; fbname=$(basename $userlistlocation) ; echo \"\$fbname\""
```