# print the last word of pattern

Tags: linux

I want to print the last word of the following pattern 
for example
/rahul/file.txt --> file.txt has to print
if the pattern is
/rahul/sample/file1.txt --> file1.txt has to print.

Easiest way is to use basename, but that is not working with my jenkins. Is there any other way to do this

Comment: Show us what jenkins is trying exactly, basename is the right application for this.

Comment: Isn't this the third post on this? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555505/basename-execution-on-remote-node https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555861/basename-command-is-not-working-in-jenkins ?

Comment: yes, whatever logic i written it didn't worked. So looking out for alternative solutions.

Comment: @Panki ssh ubuntu@$ip -n  "aws s3 cp s3://bucket/$userlistlocation . --region eu-central-1"
fbname=`basename $userlistlocation` 
echo "$fbname"

it's just printing echo echo "$fbname"

Comment: Clarification and context should be added to the question, not be given in comments.

Answer (score 0):

With `csh`, `tcsh` or `zsh`, if `$var` contains `/path/to/file`, then `$var:t` expands to the *tail* of `$var`, so `file`.

You get something similar in `vim`.

Those `:h` (head), `:t` (tail), `:r` (root), `:e` (extension) *modifiers* are also available in history expansion (csh, tcsh, bash, zsh) and glob qualifiers in `zsh`.

Beware there are some variation in behaviour between implementation for values like `/`, `//`, or `/some/dir/`.

With other shells, you can always use the `basename` command:

```
basename -- "$var"
```

Will output the *tail* of `$var` as well.

You can store that in another variable with:

```
other_var=$(basename -- "$var")
```

(though beware it won't work properly if `$var` ends in newline characters).

With POSIX shells, `${var##*/}` will expand to the content of `$var` with everything up to the rightmost `/` removed.

In any case, your *jenkins* issue is probably not related and probably down to how you execute the shell that will interpret the command you want to run.

Comment: @mosvy, you're right. I was convinced it was already in Bill Joy's `ex`/`vi`, but it's not.